# How can I get a site running under MSM (not the 'default_site') to recognise that I'm logged in?

Tags: multi-site-manager, login, cookies

I have a Multi Site Manager set up running 6 sites from a single EE installation.

I am trying to troubleshoot a problem on one of the sites and have turned on template debugging but it doesn't get shown. From past experience I have recalled that this is because the "sub-site" doesn't recognise me as being logged in as a Super Admin - even though I am logged in to the "master" site as a Super Admin.

How can I get the other sites to acknowledge that I am logged in to the CP?

Again, from memory I think I previously managed this by dropping an admin.php file into the sub-site's directory structure and logging in from that site instead of the main one. Not had time to try this again but I wondered if there was a "proper" way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Step 3 of the MSM docs**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/domainsetup.html#step-3) indicate that this is done by adding the admin.php to the web root for the site.

> Open domain2’s new admin.php file (this is the file that allows
>   Control Panel access on the new site) and make the following changes:
>
> Tip: In some multi-site situations, you may not want to allow Control
>   Panel access from anyhere other than domain1. This file can be removed
>   in those cases.
>
> Update the $system_path variable to indicate the path from this file
>   to your installation’s system folder. Typically this can be a relative
>   path, but some servers may require a full, absolute path.

```
$system_path = '../domain1.com/system/';
```